# Process.Start works for program but fails when adding arguments

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to open a file in Excel from C# code:

```
Process.Start(template == null ? "excel.exe" : $"excel.exe /r \"{template.Path}\"");
```

Running with template = null, Excel starts fine.
When template is not null, and template.Path is a valid path to an Excel document, it throws `The system cannot find the file specified`

Note that excel.exe is NOT in my PATH (running it from CMD doesn't find it), it still manages to open it apparently, from the C# code or from Run (Win + R).

From debugging the code, running in Run (Win + R) the result of `$"excel.exe /r \"{template.Path}\""` works fine and opens Excel with the file opened.

Comment: [Have you looked at the documentation for `Process.Start(string)`?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_) It states that this should be a _filename_. `excel.exe /r "somethingelse"` isn't a filename. Perhaps you need one of the other overloads?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you. I completely missed it. Feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of `Process.Start(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_), this single-string function runs a program from its path; thus adding arguments to this string is not supported as the command will try to run the full string as a program and thus failing to find it

The correct function to use is the overload `Process.Start(string path, string args)`